# Prevent use of alias in script

Tags: bash, alias

I have a `grep` alias on my .bash_profile that display line numbers and color the matches. This is an example of my `grep` results:

```
$ grep test filename
1:This is a test (to be removed)
1:This is a second test (to be removed)
```

This is my alias:

```
alias grep="grep --color"
```

Is there any way of prevent the use of that alias when the `grep` command is executed on a script?

If I tried the following commands inside my script:

```
grep test filename | sed -E 's/^(.*) \(.*$/\1/g'
\grep test filename | sed -E 's/^(.*) \(.*$/\1/g'
command grep test filename | sed -E 's/^(.*) \(.*$/\1/g'
/usr/bin/grep test filename | sed -E 's/^(.*) \(.*$/\1/g'
```

All with the following results:

```
1:This is a test
1:This is a second test
```

Will be great to get the following result:

```
This is a test
This is a second test
```

I'm using `grep (GNU grep) 2.21` and `GNU bash, version 4.3.33`.

Comment: Try `command grep ...` instead of `grep ...`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I tried, and didn't work.

Comment: Aliases don't affect scripts unless you explicitly enable them. Did you use an alias or, or did you set `GREP_OPTIONS`?

Comment: @muru I updated my question with the alias command.

Comment: Then your script has `shopt expand_aliases`, which you should consider removing, if the script is under your control. From the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html): `Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt`.

Comment: In your script, do `echo $GREP_OPTIONS`. What do you get?

Comment: @muru, no my script does not have `shopt expand_aliases`. If I `echo $GREP_OPTIONS` returns nothing.

Comment: Well: 1. Your alias as given doesn't enable line numbers. 2. The line number is repeated. I'm starting to think your file has hard-coded line numbers, or your output isn't representative. In either case, the alias is not at fault.

Comment: @muru thanks for the clues. Will look for it in that way.

Comment: Please try `awk /test/ filename` in a similar fashion to your initial `grep` statement and post the results

Comment: @roaima that works, thank you. But now, I'm interested on see what's going on with my `grep` command.

Comment: What does the `awk` output? What is output of `which grep`, `type grep`, and `ls -l $(which grep)` please

Answer (score 3):

Use `\grep`.

> The (Bourne/POSIX) shell specification says that alias substitution in
>   an interactive shell is suppressed when any character of the command
>   word is quoted.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16506263/91769

Comment: No way, didn't work for me.